# MySQL - Calculate a row value based on another row value in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 values:

- Column 1: meta_key(_regular_price), meta_value(double)
- Column 2: meta_key(_specific_country_regular_price), meta_value(double)

I want to copy the meta_value from column 2 to column 1 multiplied by the currency of the day. I'm trying without the multiplication first.

I've tried a lot of approaches, this is the last one:

```
-- 1. start a new transaction
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE 
    `_postmeta_test` 
SET 
    `meta_value` = (
            SELECT      
               t2.meta_value
            FROM 
              `_postmeta_test` t1
            JOIN `_postmeta_test` t2 
                ON t1.meta_id = t2.meta_id
                WHERE `meta_key` = '_specific_country_regular_price' )
WHERE 
    meta_key = '_regular_price' 
   
    AND `post_id` IN (
   
                SELECT 
                    `ID` 
                FROM 
                    `_posts` 
                WHERE 
                    `post_type` = 'product' 
                    AND `post_status` = 'publish' 
                   );
                   
ROLLBACK;
```

It's not working and I'm exhausted. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use joins in the `UPDATE` query, no need for all those subqueries.

```
UPDATE _postmeta_test AS t1
JOIN _posts AS p ON t1.post_id = p.ID
JOIN _postmeta_test AS t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
SET t1.meta_value = t2.meta_value * @currency_of_the_day
WHERE t1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND t2.meta_key = '_specific_country_regular_price'
AND p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, returning "0 rows affected. (Query took 8.8370 seconds.)", still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result? Maybe make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Hi Bamar, It worked changing the "ON t1.meta_id = t2.meta_id"  to "ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id"! Thanks man!